# Placeing stones/tiles on a board game

Tags: java, libgdx

I am building a board game (the Fanorama game). I would like to use a pic as the board and place the pieces on the board on top of the board sprite. Is there a nice way to pre-determine what (x,y) co-ordinate locations on the board sprite are valid for placing a piece. Later on, when the game is being played I would like to move the pieces from location to location.

Right now, the only way I can think of is to calculate each piece location pixel co-ordinates and hard-code it in an array. I am not sure if there is a better way to do this and a best practice way for me to learn. I am also concerned if this will be affected when the user resized the screen or uses a different sized device (mobile).

Comment: You might want to try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right now, the only way I can think of is to calculate each piece location pixel co-ordinates and hard-code it in an array.

Yes, this is the only way for a free form board.  You could use some math if the pieces move around the edge of the board.

> I am also concerned if this will be affected when the user resized the screen or uses a different sized device.

Yep.  Basically what you have to do is:

- Determine the displayed size of the image.
- Determine the ratio between the displayed size and the actual size.  This is usually less than 1.0 for a reduced display image.
- Calculate the new piece location pixel co-ordinates based on the ratio.  For example, if a piece location is (10, 10), and the ratio is 0.9, then the new piece location is (9, 9).  Basically, multiply the pixel co-ordinate by the ratio.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly.

To confirm, I would do this in resize() method of ApplicationListener right? Then the render method should use the new values to place the items.

Comment: @user3024231: Yes, you have the correct method.  For something as complicated as a game, be sure to [separate your model, view, and controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  Create the model first, and then the view.  Board locations would be part of the model.